# C Kernel - Runs fine in Qemu but not in VM

Tags: c, kernel

I am developing a kernel from scratch in C. I am having a problem with the keyboard. In Qemu, when I press a key on my keyboard, the keypress is handled normally. When I run it in VirtualBox or on an actual computer, it works fine until I press a key. In virtualbox, when it crashes, it gives me the error code VINF_EM_TRIPLE_FAULT. Here is my (important parts) of the code:

Assembly:

```
bits 32
section .text
        ;multiboot spec
        align 4
        dd 0x1BADB002              ;magic
        dd 0x00                    ;flags
        dd - (0x1BADB002 + 0x00)

global start
global keyboard_handler
global read_port
global write_port
global load_idt

extern main         ;this is defined in the c file
extern keyboard_handler_main

read_port:
    mov edx, [esp + 4]
            ;al is the lower 8 bits of eax
    in al, dx   ;dx is the lower 16 bits of edx
    ret

write_port:
    mov   edx, [esp + 4]    
    mov   al, [esp + 4 + 4]  
    out   dx, al  
    ret

load_idt:
    mov edx, [esp + 4]
    lidt [edx]
    sti                 ;turn on interrupts
    ret

keyboard_handler:                 
    call    keyboard_handler_main
    iretd

start:
    cli                 ;block interrupts
    mov esp, stack_space
    call main
    hlt                 ;halt the CPU

section .bss
resb 8192; 8KB for stack
stack_space:
```

C (The important parts, I omitted parts that don't involve the keyboard):

```
struct IDT_entry{
    unsigned short int offset_lowerbits;
    unsigned short int selector;
    unsigned char zero;
    unsigned char type_attr;
    unsigned short int offset_higherbits;
};

struct IDT_entry IDT[IDT_SIZE];
void idt_init(void)
{
    unsigned long keyboard_address;
    unsigned long idt_address;
    unsigned long idt_ptr[2];

    /* populate IDT entry of keyboard's interrupt */
    keyboard_address = (unsigned long)keyboard_handler;
    IDT[0x21].offset_lowerbits = keyboard_address & 0xffff;
    IDT[0x21].selector = KERNEL_CODE_SEGMENT_OFFSET;
    IDT[0x21].zero = 0;
    IDT[0x21].type_attr = INTERRUPT_GATE;
    IDT[0x21].offset_higherbits = (keyboard_address & 0xffff0000) >> 16;

    /*     Ports
    *    PIC1   PIC2
    *Command 0x20   0xA0
    *Data    0x21   0xA1
    */

    /* ICW1 - begin initialization */
    write_port(0x20 , 0x11);
    write_port(0xA0 , 0x11);

    /* ICW2 - remap offset address of IDT */
    /*
    * In x86 protected mode, we have to remap the PICs beyond 0x20 because
    * Intel have designated the first 32 interrupts as "reserved" for cpu exceptions
    */
    write_port(0x21 , 0x20);
    write_port(0xA1 , 0x28);

    /* ICW3 - setup cascading */
    write_port(0x21 , 0x00);
    write_port(0xA1 , 0x00);

    /* ICW4 - environment info */
    write_port(0x21 , 0x01);
    write_port(0xA1 , 0x01);
    /* Initialization finished */

    /* mask interrupts */
    write_port(0x21 , 0xff);
    write_port(0xA1 , 0xff);

    /* fill the IDT descriptor */
    idt_address = (unsigned long)IDT ;
    idt_ptr[0] = (sizeof (struct IDT_entry) * IDT_SIZE) + ((idt_address & 0xffff) << 16);
    idt_ptr[1] = idt_address >> 16 ;

    load_idt(idt_ptr);
}

void kb_init(void)
{
    /* 0xFD is 11111101 - enables only IRQ1 (keyboard)*/
    write_port(0x21 , 0xFD);
}
void keyboard_handler_main(void) {
    unsigned char status;
    char keycode;

    /* write EOI */
    write_port(0x20, 0x20);

    status = read_port(KEYBOARD_STATUS_PORT);
    /* Lowest bit of status will be set if buffer is not empty */
    if (status & 0x01) {
        keycode = read_port(KEYBOARD_DATA_PORT);
        if(keycode < 0){
            return;
        }
            char c = keyboard_map[(unsigned char) keycode]; //keyboard_map converts key codes to ASCII
            (prints the char)
        }
    }
}
void main(void)
{
    idt_init();
    kb_init();
    while(1);
    print("Welcome to Code OS");
}
```

And then of course they are compiled with a linker.
So why is this working in qemu but not an actual computer? (On an actual computer it works fine until I press any key.)

Comment: I cannot see a [sti] instruction, where do you set the IF back? Anyway, a Triple Fault generally indicates a bad IDT, if an hw interrupt other than the IRQ1 is requested or if an exception is raised the CPU will triple fault with your IDT. You have masked the interrupts at PIC level but nowadays PIC is obsolete and other interrupt sources are possible. Try filling the IDT with and empty handler, or better with an handler that print the interrupt number. Then look a what interrupt are raised upon a key press and try to debug. Side note: your keyboard handler is not reentrant, beware!

Comment: @knm241 Thanks. Okay, please forgive me, but I'm a beginner, and don't know where to start doing this. Do I have to change any of my assembly, or just my C? And how would I do this?

Comment: you are doing great for a beginner :) Create a tre new assembly functions: `no_eoi: iret`, `eoi_master: mov al, 20h out 20h, al iret`, `eoi_slave: mov al, 20h out a0h, al out 20h, al iret`. In C create an IDT_entry for each of this functions. Assign the no_eoi entry to IDT[0..0x1f, 0x30..0xff], assign the eoi_master to IDT[0x20..0x27] and the eoi_slave to IDT[0x28..0x2f]. This way all the IDT is filled with interrupt gates. Be sure you set this up correctly by testing, i.e. execute an int xxh instruction just after the IDT initialization then print a char and  cli-hlt.

Comment: if you see the char, the IDT is ok. Sorry for the inline code and short answer, comments are really not made for code :) BTW, have you tried booting your kernel in [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/)? It's an emulator with a debugger and a log, I find it really useful and usually I test on real machines only after having tested on Bochs.

Comment: @knm241 Thanks! I'll test it later to see if it works. I have used bochs, but this one needs GRUB to boot, so I don't know if I can do that. I'll look into that more.

Comment: @knm241 In the `out a0h, al` instruction - was a0h a typo? because it gives me an error, and so does ah. EDIT: It's `mov a0h, al` right?

Comment: @knm241 Also, when you say assign it to [0..0x1f] do you mean anywhere in there or all of them within that range?

Comment: a0h is meant to be 0a0h, sorry (the address of the slave PIC). By [0..0x1f] I mean all of them. The goal is to have every descriptor in the IDT filled

Comment: @knm241 Okay, thanks! I'm not home right now, but I'll test it when I get home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79341/discussion-between-user3042719-and-knm241).